# Input type="file" in iFrame in PhoneGap Build

Tags: html, cordova, iframe, input-type-file

I have a PhoneGap built HTML app, which has an iFrame through to a web system

One page of this system is a very simple file upload using

```
< input type="file"> etc...
```

In a webOS environment this works perfectly, however in PhoneGap build clearly the

```
<input type="file"> doesnt work.
```

I am searching - somewhat desperately - for a solution, where I can change the

```
<input type="file">
```

to something to make it work. Simplicity is key here as the iframe points to a very complex existing system which I am reluctant to make any major changes too.

Thank you in advance for all your help

Regards

Henry

Comment: Hi Henry, I have same question as you which would like to use file upload in iframe.. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Hi Red23Jordan...

I utilised the child broswer instead of an iFrame, much more responsive. Its effectivly a toolbar-less browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for me, the input file doesn't work in Phonegap.

You need use the Phonegap API to get picture and select the source where come from, like photolibrary, camera or savedphotoalbum.

See more info about camera.getPicture: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture and about Camera.PictureSourceType parameter of cameraOptions method: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions